# HXT: Surprising behavior when reading and writing HTML to String in pure code

Tags: haskell, hxt

I want to read HTML from a String, process it and return the changed document as a String using HXT. As this operation does not require IO, I would rather execute the Arrow with `runLA` than with `runX`.

The code look like this (omitting the processing for simplicity):

```
runLA (hread >>> writeDocumentToString [withOutputHTML, withIndent yes]) html
```

However, the surrounding `html` tag is missing in the result:

```
["\n  <head>\n    <title>Bogus</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n        Some trivial bogus text.\n    </body>\n",""]
```

When I use runX instead like this:

```
runX (readString [] html >>> writeDocumentToString [withOutputHTML, withIndent yes])
```

I get the expected result:

```
["<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Bogus</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n        Some trivial bogus text.\n    </body>\n</html>\n"]
```

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the `XmlTree`s for both, you'll see that `readString` adds a top-level `"/"` element. For the non-`IO` `runLA` version:

```
> putStr . formatTree show . head $ runLA xread html
---XTag "html" []
   |
   +---XText "\n  "
   |
   +---XTag "head" []
   ...
```

And with `runX`:

```
> putStr . formatTree show . head =<< runX (readString [] html)
---XTag "/" [NTree (XAttr "transfer-Status") [NTree (XText "200")...
   |
   +---XTag "html" []
       |
       +---XText "\n  "
       |
       +---XTag "head" []
       ...
```

`writeDocumentToString` uses `getChildren` to strip off this root element.

One easy way around this is to use something like `selem` to wrap the output of `xread` in a similar root element, in order to make it look like the kind of input `writeDocumentToString` expects:

```
> runLA (selem "/" [xread] >>> writeDocumentToString [withOutputHTML, withIndent yes]) html
["<html>\n  <head>\n    <title>Bogus</title>\n  </head>\n  <body>\n        Some trivial bogus text.\n    </body>\n</html>\n"]
```

This produces the desired output.