# Write an entire XML document to String using HXT

Tags: haskell, hxt

I'm trying to figure out how to perform some XML transformations with [HXT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt), but I can't figure out how to output an entire document to a string. While the documentation shows how to use `readDocument` and `writeDocument`, these run in `IO`, and I'm trying to figure out how to do a pure transformation.

(Incidentally: why is so much of HXT defined as impure functions? One of the main advantages of Haskell is, in my opinion, that the compiler can guarantee the purity of functions. If I didn't care about that, I could have accomplished my XML goal already by writing my application in another language.)

I've figured out how to read an XML string with HXT:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> x = "<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>"
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runLA xread x
[NTree (XTag "foo" []) [NTree (XTag "bar" []) [NTree (XText "baz") []]]]
```

That works, as one can see, as expected.

Next, I'd like to write the `XmlTree` back to a `String`:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runLA (xread >>> writeDocumentToString []) x
["<bar>baz</bar>"]
```

This is the heart of **my question**: *where's the `foo` element?*

Why doesn't that arrow round-trip? Why isn't the output `"<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>"`?

---

In order to trouble-shoot, I've tried to print the Haskell representation:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> runLA (xread >>> writeDocumentToString [withShowHaskell yes]) x
["NTree (XTag \"foo\" []) [NTree (XTag \"bar\" []) [NTree (XText \"baz\") []]]"]
```

In this representation, the outermost `foo` element is still present.

One can also demonstrate this by printing the tree:

```
Prelude Text.XML.HXT.Core> putStrLn $ unlines $ runLA (xread >>> writeDocumentToString [withShowTree yes]) x
---XTag "foo"
   |
   +---XTag "bar"
       |
       +---XText "baz"
```

Again, it seems quite clear that the `foo` element is still there.

How can I serialise an `XmlTree` to a `String` while preserving the entire document, including the root?

Comment: A potential hack is to wrap it in a dummy root element before serializing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208559/hxt-surprising-behavior-when-reading-and-writing-html-to-string-in-pure-code

Comment: @DarthFennec Thank you! While I did try to search for a solution before I wrote my question, I didn't find that one. Voting to close my own question as a duplicate.